# Access multiple database in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

This is my code:

```
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:////root/Desktop/Social_Network/users.db'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_BINDS'] = {'posts': 'sqlite:////root/Desktop/Social_Network/posts.db'}

class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=True, nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(40), unique=True, nullable=False)
    password = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    joined_at = db.Column(db.DateTime(),default =datetime.datetime.now)
    is_hero = db.Column(db.Boolean(),default=False)

class Post(db.Model):
    __bind_key__ = 'posts' 
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    user = db.Column(db.String(50))
    post = db.Column(db.String(255))
    score = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    downVotes = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False )
    posted_time = db.Column(db.DateTime(),default =datetime.datetime.now)
    upVotes = db.Column(db.Integer,nullable=False)

dict_ = {}
def get_all_users():
    users_ = User.query.all()
    global dict_
    for user in users_:
        dict_[user.email] = user.password
    return dict_
```

I have connected multiple databases in SQLAlchemy. My problem is whenever I run :

```
users_ = User.query.all()
```

. It returns the User object, but after I run the change it to post, something like this:

```
post = Post.query.all()
```

It returns none. Any help regarding this issue?

Comment: Do you have any posts in the database? You can easily check by doing `sqlite3 /root/Desktop/Social_Network/posts.db .dump`

Comment: Yes.I have. It is working I guess!

Comment: May I ask why you need separate files? And not just separate tables?